# How do I set the value of multiple inputs with the Air Datepicker Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm having trouble manually setting the date (value) of multiple inputs using the Air Datepicker plugin. It always sets just the Pickup date field, but neglects the Delivery date field.

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <div id="pickupDate" class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <label class="control-label">Requested Pickup Date <span class="normal">(No Weekend Pickup Available)</span></label>
        <input name="datereqPick" type="text" id="datereqPick" class="form-control clearable" value='' tabindex="1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="deliveryDate" class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <label class="control-label">Delivery Date</label>
        <input name="datereqDel" type="text" id="datereqDel" class="form-control clearable" value='' tabindex="2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
// Initialize Datepicker
var disabledDays = [0, 6],
    datepicker = $('#datereqPick, #datereqDel').datepicker().data('datepicker'),
    $picker = $('#datereqPick, #datereqDel');
$picker.datepicker({
    language: 'en',
    autoClose: true,
    minDate: new Date(),
    onRenderCell: function(date, cellType) {
        if (cellType == 'day') {
            var day = date.getDay(),
                isDisabled = disabledDays.indexOf(day) != -1;
            return {
                disabled: isDisabled
            };
        }
    },
    onSelect: function(formattedDate, date, inst) {
        datepicker.hide();
    }
});

// Set Dates Manually
$picker.data('datepicker').selectDate(new Date('11/30/2016'));
```

});

**Fiddle**

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/mp55sqdd/1/

Thanks in advance for your help!